# Persisting Ordered Domain Objects

Tags: java, hibernate, web-applications, orm, domain-driven-design

A very common use case in many web applications is that domain objects can be ordered by a user in the web interface - and that order is persisted for later; but I've noticed that every time I need to implement this, I always end up coming up with a solution that is different and adds considerable weight and complexity to a simple domain object.  As an example, suppose I have the persistent entity Person

```
Person {
   long id
   String name
}
```

A user goes to `/myapp/persons` and sees all people in the system in the order in which they receive compensation (or something) - all of the people can be clicked and dragged and dropped into another position - when the page is loaded again, the order is remembered.  The problem is that relational databases just don't seem to have a good way of doing this; nor do ORMs (hibernate is what I use)

I've been thinking of a generic ordering methodology - but there will be some overhead as the data would be persisted separately which could slow down access in some use cases.  My question is: has anyone come up with a really good way to model the order of persistent domain objects?

I work in JavaEE with Hibernate or JDBCTemplate - so any code examples would be most useful with those technologies as their basis.  Or any conceptual ideas would be welcome too.

UPDATE:  I'm not sure where I went wrong, but it seems I was unclear as most have responded with responses that don't really match my question (as it is in my head).  The problem is not how do I order rows or columns when I fetch them - it is that the order of the domain objects change - someone clicks and drags a "person" from the bottom of the list to the top of the list - they refresh the page and the list is now in the order they specified.

Answer (score 1):

When fetching results, just build HQL queries with a different ORDER BY clause, depending on what the user has used last time

Comment: The issue with this is it still leave the complex task of updating changes to the order of individual domain objects to the implementer for each domain object.  There will not be any way to sort the list because the sorting is based on a user specified order.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that relational databases just don't seem to have a good way of doing this; nor do ORMs (hibernate is what I use)

I'm not sure where you would get this impression. [Hibernate specifically has support for mapping indexed collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-indexed) (which is a "list" by another name), which usually boils down to storing a "list-index" column in the table holding the collection of items.

An example taken directly from the manual:

```
<list name="carComponents"
    table="CarComponents">
    <key column="carId"/>
    <list-index column="sortOrder"/>
    <composite-element class="CarComponent">
        <property name="price"/>
        <property name="type"/>
        <property name="serialNumber" column="serialNum"/>
    </composite-element>
</list>
```

This would allow a `List<CarComponents>` to be associated with your root entity, stored in the `CarComponents` table with a `sortOrder` column.

Answer (score 1):

One possible generic solution:

Create a table to persist sort information, simplest case would be be one sortable field per entity with a direction:

```
table 'sorts'
* id: PK
* entity: String
* field: String
* direction: ASC/DESC enumeration (or ascending boolean flag)
```

It could be made more complicated by adding a userId to do per-user sorting or by adding a sort_items table with a foreign key to support sorting by multiple fields at a time.

Once you're persisting the sort information, it's a simple matter of adding Order instances to criteria (if that's what you're using) or concatenating order by statements to your HQL.

This also keeps your entities themselves free of and ordinal information, which in this case sounds like the right approach since the ordering is purely for user interaction purposes.

**Update - Persisting entity order**
Given the fact that you want to be able to reorder entities, not just define a sort for them, then you really do need to make an ordinal or index value part of the entity's definition.

The problem, as I'm sure you realize is the number of entities that would need to be updated, with the worst case scenario being moving the last entity to the top of the list.

You could use an increment value other than 1 (say 10) so you would have:

```
ordinal | name
10      | Crosby
20      | Stills
30      | Nash
40      | Young
```

Most of the time, updating the row would involve selecting two items and updating one.  If I want to move Young to position 2, I select current item 2 and the previous item from the database to get the ordinals 10 and 20.  Use these to create the new ordinal ((20 - 10) / 2 + 10 = 15).  Now do a single update of Young with an ordinal of 15.

If you get to the point where division by two yields the same index as one of the entities you just loaded, that means it's time to spawn a task to normalize the ordinal values according to your original increment.

Comment: Obviously this adds some additional DB overhead, but that is easily tended to with a good caching strategy.

Comment: this is actually quite close to the way I'm looking at the problem - it doesn't really explain how entities could be moved (unless it is based on the PK)

Comment: I ended up using an approach similar to this, at some point I will add code snippets and so on, but this is the closest to my solution

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, JPA 2.0 provides support for ordered lists:
https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Order_Column_.28JPA_2.0.29

Comment: I think he wants dynamic ordering, not static.

Comment: He seems to want to load the list in the same order as stored, which should be supported by this solution. Or what do you mean by "static" and "dynamic" ordering? The question is however if he wants to store this information per user or if it should be the same for all users.

Comment: The entity with an ordered list will be taken from the DAO/Repository and detached when it is added to the model and displayed.  The user can then just move the ordered objects around - how would this be communicated back to the database?  If I save I don't want it to just bulk update all listed objects, there could be many.  A code example would help

Comment: Well, as he's implementing a web interface he could e.g. use a stateful Gateway and use an EntityManager with an extended persistence context. (see "Real World Java EE Patterns - Rethinking Best Practices" by Adam Bien)

Comment: Upon further inspection of the link: the issue is not how do I order the objects, a simple comparator could do that job.  The problem is how do I manage the order of many objects without making excessive database calls, or dealing with problems syncing the list (and its order) in memory to the database

Comment: Oh, you're the OP :-) Have a look at the Gateway solution (work with attached not with detached entities). Together with the mentioned annotation this solution should work, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think that relational databases cannot do better than a dedicated ordering column.

The idea of "order" is not really defined in SQL for anything but cursors, and they are not a core relational concept but rather an implementation detail.

For all I know the only thing to do is to abstract the ordering column away with @OrderColumn (JPA2, so Hibernate 3.5+ compatibile).